How do i get the selected item from a list when using vue3-virtual-scroll-list library
I have a nuxt3 project, I am using vue3-virtual-scroll-list to display a list of items in a dropdown. Here is the code that displays the virtual list
<virtual-list style="height: 360px; overflow-y: auto;" 
   :data-key="'symbol'"
   :data-sources="currentPairs" 
   :data-component="VirtualScrollTemplate" 
/>

VirtualScrollTemplate is a component imported that has this code in it, just to define the template of how the items in the list wil be displayed.
<template>
    <div class="text-primary-gray border border-red-900">{{ index }} - {{ source.symbol }}</div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    export default {
      name: 'item-component',
      props: {
        index: { // index of current item
          type: Number
        },
        source: { // here is: {uid: 'unique_1', text: 'abc'}
          type: Object,
          default () {
            return {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

From the documentation i couldn't find a prop or method that holds the selected item from the list when it is clicked. How do i get the value?
I have tried to emit the data from VirtualScrollTemplate to the Virtual List component, but it didn't work. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about it?

As a workaround, I had to save the data to pinia state, so I can access it from anywhere in the app, since the library does not provide a way to hold the selected value from the list.
